# C# MVVM Combobox

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, combobox, selecteditem

In XAML I have a combobox defined as:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UsernameComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Username" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Right now, it doesn't show any default selected item.

I fill the combo box with a list:

```
public List<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        return _userRepository.RetrieveUsers();
    }
}

public List<User> RetrieveUsers()
{
    _users = (from Users in _db.Users select Users).ToList();

    return _users;
}
```

The proper Users being the ItemSource for the combobox. then in the XAML I defined SelectedItem and bound it to a property called Selected name.

In code this looks like:

```
    private User _selectedName;
    public User SelectedName
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedName;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (_selectedName == value) return;
            _selectedName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
        }
    }
```

How can I get my combobox to show a selectedItem at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I can see is that each time `Users` property is accessed, the `RetrieveUsers()` method is invoked which re-runs your database query. This is going to upset your `SelectedItem` binding which will expect the list of items bound to the `ComboBox` to be unchanged. In other words, it finds the selected item by evaluating the equality of the `SelectedItem` against the collection of bound items.

You need to query the database once ...

```
public YourClassConstructor()
{
   _users = _userRepository.RetrieveUsers();
   _selectedName = _users[0];
}

public List<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        return _users;
    }
}
```

This will also ensure that the first item is selected.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice answer indeed. I especially thank you for pointing out that I keep querying the database. For this application atleast it is highly unneeded. Also I will see how it will affect the combobox using a "static" list. Thanks again.

Comment: That's a bit extreme! - anyhow, glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

There are some [performance implications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#Binding_to_an_ItemsSource) you should consider when choosing to bind to a non-observable collection. The update time is significantly faster if you bind to an observable collection instead of a simple list.

You should take a look at using an items source that implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface, such as an [ObservableCollection{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) collection or expose your items source in your view model using [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx). Also take a look at this information about [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec6) in the context of MVVM.

I personally prefer exposing items sources in my view models using ICollectionView. Silverlight provides the [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class, and WPF provides the [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) class.

```
public ICollectionView Users
{
    get
    {
        if (_viewModelUsers == null)
        {
            _viewModelUsers = new PagedCollectionView(_viewModelUsersSource);
        }
        return _viewModelUsers;
    }
}
private ICollectionView _viewModelUsers;
private ObservableCollection<User> _viewModelUsersSource = new ObservableCollection<User>();
```

You can then use [MoveCurrentToFirst()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.movecurrenttofirst.aspx) to set the selected item after populating the underlying source collection using a call to your repository.

Comment: The collection is not changing so this is not relevant.